Issues in solving a differential equation for a modified matrix
Following program works fine as it gives a solution to the differential equation here
$Assumptions = a > 0 && b > 0 && g1 > 0 && g2 > 0 && t > 0
matV = {{a, b}, {b, a}}; 
A1 = {{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[g1], 0}}; A1T = Transpose[A1]; 
A2 = {{0, Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[g2]}, {0, 0}}; A2T = Transpose[A2]; 
diss1[x_] := A1 . x . A1T - (1/2)*(A1T . A1 . x + x . A1T . A1)
diss2[x_] := A2 . x . A2T - (1/2)*(A2T . A2 . x + x . A2T . A2)
R[t_] = {{r00[t], r01[t]}, {r10[t], r11[t]}}; 
ini = R[0] == {{R00, R01}, {R10, R11}}; 
sol = DSolve[{D[R[t], t] == (-I)*(matV . R[t] - R[t] . matV) + diss1[R[t]] + 
      diss2[R[t]], ini}, Flatten[R[t]], t]
Rf = R[t] /. Flatten[sol]

Now with matU = ( { {x, 1 - x}, {y, 1 - y} } ); where x and y are both real and positive, I want to solve the above differential equation but for a new matrix
Rnew[t_] = matU . {{r00[t], r01[t]}, {r10[t], r11[t]}}; 
ininew = R[0] == matU . {{R00, R01}, {R10, R11}}; 
solnew = DSolve[{D[Rnew[t], t] == (-I)*(matV . R[t] - Rnew[t] . matV) + diss1[Rnew[t]] + 
      diss2[Rnew[t]], ininew}, Flatten[Rnew[t]], t]

But I get the following error message DSolve:x r00[t]+(1-x) r10[t] cannot be used as a function. How can one solve the above equaiton correctly?

MatrixForm is a wrapper for printing a list to look like a matrix. If you want to define A1 and A2 as matrices just get rid of the MatrixForms:
$$
$$
A1 = {{0, 0}, {Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[g1], 0}}; A1T = Transpose[A1];
$$
$$
A2 = {{0, Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[g2]}, {0, 0}}; A2T = Transpose[A2];

@ydd, thanks, I don't know how that MatrixForm crept in while copying the code. In my program, I did not have the matrix form. Anyway, I have corrected it here, but the problem remains: I get the same warning message!

I think you want to use Flatten[R[t]] as the dependent variables, not Flatten[Rnew[t]], right?

Also I would recommend reading the DSolve documentation on how to solve differential equations for matrix-valued dependent variables; it can make the code a lot cleaner and easier to catch errors.
